# Why is numpy.random.binomial(1, nan) = -9223372036854775807?

Tags: python, numpy, nan

As in the title, I would expect it to be a nan as well.  Is this  number special?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is clearly a bug in `numpy.ramdom.binomial`.

> Is this number special?

I would guess this is the result of some calculation involving the *raw representation* of `nan` (which is represented as a specific "reserved" float value).   ([More on that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN#Encoding))

The implementor probably forgot to check input for `nan` and included the raw representation of `nan` in the (C-level) calculation.

Comment: You can also see this in `np.array(np.nan).astype(int)`.  This gets caught if you try `np.array(np.nan, int)` but not with the above, which just interprets the data as if it were `int`.